# QGIS Toolbox for Loop Routes?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, routing, network

I am looking for a function or toolbox which allows for generating loop routes subject to constraints. It would look something like:

| Attribute | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Network | Routing network | OSM extract |
| Start/End | A selected point | #1 1st Street |
| minDistance | Minimum distance | 8 miles |
| maxDistance | Maximum distance | 10 miles |
| objectiveDirection | min/max | min |
| Objective | attribute to min/max | distance |

With this example, it would use the OpenStreetMap extract layer, start the route at #1 1st Street, generate a route between 8-10 miles, not use the same segments twice, end at #1 1st Street, and minimize the sum of the distance attribute over these segments. ie try to generate a loop as close to 8 miles as possible without going under.

Objective function could be a different derived attribute attached to every segment in the network, like elevation gain, tree cover, etc that you want to either minimize or maximize on the loop route.

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you have a look at the tools available in `Menu Processing / Toolbox /Network` (like the tool `Shortest Path`) - see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html Also have a look at QNEAT3 plugin: https://root676.github.io/ I guess chances to get an answer would be better if you told us where you're stuck using these (or any other) tools.

Comment: Also consider using Graphic modeler: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/processing/modeler_twi.html - For min/max distance with the tools mentioned above, you probably have to run the tools twice.

Comment: Hi @Karson; I'm looking to solve the exact same problem. I have had no success yet, but did find this paper (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-38527-8_25), which seems to solve the same issue. Unfortunately, the authors no longer have the code available. I have looked at using OSRM, Valhalla and Graphhopper, but not seem to have this functionality 'out of the box' and would require some 'custom' work. I'm curious if you have made any progress since your post?